# docker compose run bash command on start

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose file, where I combine nginx and a node js app. I need to run the shell command `sudo sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=65536` when the whole thing starts, but I can't find a clear example how to do it.

This is my node app dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.9.0

ADD . /myapi
WORKDIR /myapi

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 1337

ENTRYPOINT ["node"]
CMD ["./index.js"]
```

This is my nginx dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
MAINTAINER me
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY ssl-certificates/ServerCertificate.cer /var/www/ssl/ServerCertificate.cer
COPY ssl-certificates/SSLPrivateKey.key /var/www/ssl/SSLPrivateKey.key
```

And this is my docker compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
    api:
        image: myregistry/my-api:1.033
    build: ./api
    ports:
        - "1337"
    environment:
        NODE_ENV: qa
    deploy:
        replicas: 12
    networks:
        - api-network
proxy:
    image: myregistry/my-api-proxy:1.033
    build:
        context: ./nginx
        args:
            RUNNING_MODE: prod
    ulimits:
        nproc: 65535
        nofile:
            soft: 10240
            hard: 20480
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    links:
        - api
    deploy:
        replicas: 3
    networks:
        - api-network

networks:
  api-network:
      driver: overlay
```

A clear example will be very appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use `ENTRYPOINT` as below:

```
FROM node:6.9.0

ADD . /myapi
WORKDIR /myapi 

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 1337

ENTRYPOINT "/bin/node index.js" && "sudo sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=65536"
```